# Android app not able to post data on firebase

Tags: android, firebase

i have an android app which need to post data on firebase. It work perfectly when i test it with my development device.

when i publish it on store and my friend want to post data on same firebase account --- it not work --- no error message -- no crash --- just no data on server.

I need to ask that free plan of firebase works in such scenario with published app on Google store ? or i need to upgrade it with paid plan.

My code is below:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(my_URL); 

String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString(); 
String date = Utility.getDateTime(); 

Firebase jobchild = ref.child(projectId); 
jobchild.setValue(uniqueID);

Firebase jimages = jobchild.child("ProjectId"); 
jimages.setValue(projectId); 

Firebase jdate = jobchild.child("LogDate"); 
jdate.setValue(date);
```

Comment: The free plan should work. Can you share any relevant code?

Comment: *Firebase engineer here.* This should not be related to being on a free plan. But without some more information on how to reproduce this problem, it will be impossible to help further. Is there any way you could create an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: thanks for the sharing that it is not due to plan.
code sample for the adding data to server is as below:

                        Firebase ref = new Firebase(my_URL);
   String  uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   String date = Utility.getDateTime();
   Firebase jobchild = ref.child(projectId);
   jobchild.setValue(uniqueID);

   Firebase jimages = jobchild.child("ProjectId");
   jimages.setValue(projectId);

   Firebase jdate = jobchild.child("LogDate");
   jdate.setValue(date);

Comment: There's still not enough info here to repro the issue. See the link Puf provided.

Answer (score 3):

When I put your code into an Android app, it works fine for me:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/32319324");

// Ensure we start out with no data at this location
ref.removeValue();

// Monitor the location and output any data there to a text view
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        TextView output = (TextView) Activity32319324.this.findViewById(R.id.content_32319324);
        for (DataSnapshot project: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            output.setText(
                "key="+project.getKey() + "\n" +
                "LogDate="+project.child("LogDate").getValue() + "\n" +
                "ProjectId="+project.child("ProjectId").getValue()+"\n\n"
            );
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});

// Write data to the location
String projectId = "42";
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String date = new Date().toString(); //Utility.getDateTime();

Firebase jobchild = ref.child(projectId);
jobchild.setValue(uniqueID);

Firebase jimages = jobchild.child("ProjectId");
jimages.setValue(projectId);

Firebase jdate = jobchild.child("LogDate");
jdate.setValue(date);
```

[image: the output of the activity]

See the app here: https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android (your code is in Activity32319324)